# Are the .job files created using the C# TaskScheduler library obsolete for Windows 7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I am using this library http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx to try and schedule tasks for Windows 7. When I create a task the file extension it is saving it as is .job which I think was fine for scheduling tasks in Windows XP. For Windows 7 it is not recognizing the .job file extension and is looking solely for a .xml file.

Is this library obsolete for Windows 7 or am I missing something altogether?
Is there a way to tie the .job files into Windows 7?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task Scheduler 1.0 was used in Windows 2000/XP/Server 2003.  However, the differences in the file types and content are a result of Microsoft changing the way Windows handles tasks with Task Scheduler 2.0, which is used in Vista, 7, and Server 2008.  With 2.0, came the switch to XML-based files and a few more features.

Perhaps you should try adding the Task Scheduler 2.0 API to your project and using that.

This is an article I found: http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/23/calling-the-task-scheduler-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008-from-managed-code.aspx

HTH.

Comment: Thank you I will try that kind sir and get back to you with the results! /tiphat